# Django: avoid RelatedObjectDoesNotExist for new objects

Tags: django

I have a question regarding Django to which I already have a work-around; but I simply find it hard to believe that this is the actual idiom, so I'm very much open to better suggestions.

Consider de following models:

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    not_null = models.ForeignKey("self", null=False)
    nullable = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)
```

And the following REPL-session:

```
>>> Experiment().not_null is None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  [..]
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Experiment has no not_null.
>>> Experiment().not_null_id is None
True
>>> Experiment().nullable is None
True
```

My concern is about the first line of the REPL-session failing. I'd like to be able to check for proper initialization, but I cannot do so idiomatically.

My surprise is about the following: Django raises a DB-related exception (suggesting that there was actually an attempt to look this up in the DB); whereas there would be no need to actually go to the DB to figure out the field is not set. I don't want to be forced to catch an exception that shouldn't have been raised in the first place.

As evidenced, you can work around this by postpending `_id`, but this is a hack IMHO.

*now for the question*:

Is there a more idiomatic way to figure out whether a non-nullable field has already been set on newly created object?
I cannot find this in the documentation.

Comment: If you don't set `not_null`, an exception will be raised when you call `self.save()` or `self.full_clean()`. I think those are the most idiomatic ways to check this. Since there's some magical metaprogramming underlying Django's ORM models, accessing attributes works different than in plain python classes. And in any case, there's lots gotchas when handling new unsaved model instances instead of instances that exists in the database. I think that catching `DoesNotExist` is a perfectly fine and idiomatic way to handle this.

Comment: @HåkenLid thanks for the additional pointers.

I suppose a good counter-question to my original question would be: under which circumstances does it make sense to pass around not-yet-valid new instances in the application? I _did_ at least identify a few cases of that in my existing code, e.g. creating half of an object using a form w/ `commit=False`; doing the rest later.

Comment: Forms is one case. There could also be performance reasons why you would want to minimize reading and writing to the database, since that can be a significant bottle neck. I don't know if there's a lot of best practices for handling unsaved model instances, though. It might be worth checking out the source code for django's forms framework or the serializers in django-rest-framework for ideas.